# Verify length of each string of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to make a verification that if one of these strings has a length greater than 40 echo "this array contains a string with a length greater than 40". So in this case the index [11] contains a string length that is greater than 40. How can I do that?

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "PEDRO MOACIR LANDIM"
  [1]=>
  string(19) "ADIR JOAO GASTALDON"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "ABEL PEDRO MARQUES"
  [10]=>
  string(28) "ADRIANO CESAR GARCIA JOAQUIM"
  [11]=>
  string(44) "AUTO VIAÇÃO CATARINENSE LTDA - FLORIANÓPOLIS"
}
```

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php to get the length of a string.

Comment: I would use `array_filter()`. This will return you list of array elements, which are longer than 40.

Comment: "strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string. " in this case `strlen()` is the wrong function @JasonK because this is UTF8 data. [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) needs to be used.

Comment: @cyadvert But he only needs to know if it contains a string that has more than 40 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 if(mb_strlen($value) > 40){
  echo "this array contain a string wich lenght is greater than 40: ".$key;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since only one of the strings is needed to be detected if it's greater than 40, it's better to break the loop once a number greater than 40 is encountered. This can reduce the number of iterations executed by your for loop if ever the number isn't located at the last index of your array.

```
foreach ($array as $arr) {
 if(mb_strlen($arr) > 40){
  echo "this array contain a string wich length is greater than 40";
  break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<?php

    $myStrings = array(

    0 => "PEDRO MOACIR LANDIM",
    1 => "ADIR JOAO GASTALDON",
    2 =>  "ABEL PEDRO MARQUES",
    10 =>  "ADRIANO CESAR GARCIA JOAQUIM",
    11 => "AUTO VIAÇÃO CATARINENSE LTDA - FLORIANÓPOLIS"
    );

    foreach($myStrings as $key => $string){

    //Get length of string

    $len = strlen( $string );

if( $len > 40 ){

    echo 
    'this array contain a string wich length is greater than 40. Array key: 
    ' .$key. ' | array string: ' .$string;

    break;

 }

}

?>
```